# Rails Javascript Error - TypeError: $(...).S3Uploader is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, typeerror

I am trying to use the [s3_direct_upload](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload) gem, which has worked before in the past.

However, when I load the page, I get the following error: **TypeError: $(...).S3Uploader is not a function**

However, when I view the page source for the webpage, it shows that in fact, the "/assets/s3_direct_upload.js?body=1" file has loaded, which means it should be defining the "S3Uploader" function.

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require s3_direct_upload
```

I have tried deleting all the "public/application.js" files and restarting the server, but this did not appear to work.

Any ideas on what may be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Turns out, jQuery was being loaded twice (which was completely my error).

One instance was in "application.js" and again in "views/layouts/application.html.erb."  I removed it from "application.js" and the error went away!